# How do I stop a number from going into negative

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, button

I have been "writing" a game which involves you collecting a resource, you then spend those resources on something which then creates more of that resource (it will be more interesting when i have finished).

Anyway, my question is that i cannot find a way to stop the number of resources from going into a negative value after buying too much of the thing that creates more resources. I need some way of disabling the button.

I would also like to know how to show the number that is a percentage of the total trees:)

To make it easier, here is the code...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Game</title>
  <script>
    function collectSeeds() {
      document.getElementById("Seeds").stepUp(1);
    }

    function plantTree() {
      document.getElementById("Seeds").stepDown(10);
      document.getElementById("Trees").stepUp(1);
    }

    function plantTrees10() {
      document.getElementById("Seeds").stepDown(100);
      document.getElementById("Trees").stepUp(10);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="collectSeeds()">Collect Seeds</button>
  <button type="button" id="plantTree" 
    onClick="myTimer = setInterval(collectSeeds, 1000); plantTree();">Plant Tree</button>
  <button 
    onClick="plantTrees10(); myTimer = setInterval(collectSeeds,100);">Plant Trees (10)</button>
  <p>Seeds
    <br/>
    <input type="number" id="Seeds" disabled></input>
    <p>Trees
      <br/>
      <input type="number" id="Trees" disabled></input>
      <div style="position: fixed; bottom: 0; right: 0;">Progress:</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. add min and max to the field as explained in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement)
2. You likely want to give a message somewhere too.
3. Lastly clear the interval before using it again - I rewrote the script to be unobtrusive and generic.

```js
var myTimer; // make global in scope
function collectSeeds() {
  document.getElementById("Seeds").stepUp(1);
}

function plantTree(but) {
  var nofSeeds = parseInt(but.getAttribute("data-nofseeds"), 10),
    availableSeeds = parseInt(document.getElementById("Seeds").value, 10);
  if (availableSeeds < nofSeeds) {
    console.log(availableSeeds + " not enough, " + nofSeeds + " needed"); // give some message somewhere
    return;
  }
  console.log(nofSeeds)
  document.getElementById("Seeds").stepDown(10 * nofSeeds);
  document.getElementById("Trees").stepUp(nofSeeds);
}

window.onload = function() {
  var plantButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".plantTree");
  for (var i = 0; i < plantButtons.length; i++) {
    plantButtons[i].onclick = function() {
      clearInterval(myTimer); // only have one timer running
      myTimer = setInterval(collectSeeds, 1000);
      plantTree(this);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="collectSeeds()">Collect Seeds</button>
<button type="button" class="plantTree" data-nofseeds="1">Plant Tree</button>
<button type="button" class="plantTree" data-nofseeds="10">Plant Trees (10)</button>
<p>Seeds
  <br/>
  <input type="number" min="0" max="1000" id="Seeds" disabled />
</p>
<p>Trees
  <br/>
  <input type="number" id="Trees" disabled />
</p>
<div style="position: fixed; bottom: 0; right: 0;">Progress:</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution. Although, I did notice that if you click on the "plant tree" button repeatedly, it still effects the number of seeds per second. It would be greatly appreciated if you could show me the answer.

Comment: Try clearInterval(myTimer); before setting it - assuming you want to plant at intervals

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again. I don't understand where you want me to put the clearInterval(myTimer);

Comment: Please see update. It is a rather large update, I hope you follow the changes. I now have only one function that takes the number of seeds fromt the data attribute of the button

Comment: Thank you so much! This has saved me so much time!

Answer (score 0):

Just add if it should work just fine...

```
function plantTree() {
  if (document.getElementById("Seeds").value < 10) {
    alert("you don't have enough resources")
  } else {
  document.getElementById("Seeds").stepDown(10);
  document.getElementById("Trees").stepUp(1);
}
}
function plantTrees10() {
      if (document.getElementById("Seeds").value < 100) {
        alert("you don't have enough resources")
      } else {
      document.getElementById("Seeds").stepDown(100);
      document.getElementById("Trees").stepUp(10);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. This was simple but it still worked really well.